# Toggle on/off the USB port of an arduino pro micro

Tags: arduino, usb, charge

I am using an arduino pro micro which has a wifi chip connected to it to run commands on a cellphone remotely (via otg). I have attached a Y cable to the arduino and to a charger, however i can not charge the phone and use the OTG functionality at the same time. 
I am trying to figure out a way to send a command to the arduino pro micro to disable the usb port, this way the phone will automatically go into charge mode.

Thank you

Comment: You're using a Y USB cable? I can't visualise your set up.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Micro-Cable-Samsung-Player-OTHERS/dp/B00CXAC1ZW/ this is the Y cable, it has a power input which connects to the otg device and to the micro usb male which powers the cellphone.

Comment: So your wi-fi unit takes/gives commands from/to from the Arduino? The male micro USB connector plugs into your phone? The female  USB micro into the charger? That only leaves one end to plug in both Arduino and wi-fi? I'm just not picturing this!

Comment: yes the pro micro is connected to the USB female via an adapter. the wifi chip esp8266 is soldered onto the pro micro

Comment: In which case, I don't understand why you're not just charging the phone directly from the Arduino. Why the need for the Y cable? I'm assuming that this wi-fi chip is connected via SPI or UART to the Arduino then. A  diagram would be v useful.

Comment: http://ibb.co/h3ebpk this is a rough image of the setup

Comment: To clarify: is the Arduino your USB host, and the phone is as USB device, right? Or the phone is OTG host, and Arduino is USB device?

Comment: The phone is the OTG host, it takes in commands from the arduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of simply disabling of Arduino USB port won't work. Here is why.

If the phone is OTG and you want it to be in host mode, then the issue of charging becomes a bit challenging. The issue is that in host mode a normal USB port is a source of VBUS, which contradicts to the desire to keep the phone charging (receive power).

The standard official USB solution is in so-called "accessory charging" scheme. This is an optional mode, and might be not supported by your mobile device (smartphone).

In most simplistic OTG case the role of USB port is determined by the state of ID pin in micro-USB connector. The ID is supplied from cable's overmold. If the ID pin is floating, the phone must  behave as device. If the ID pin is grounded, the phone must switch into host mode, and drive VBUS. Therefore the role of OTG port can't be changed by disabling USB functionality on device side, it is mechanically defined by ID pin inside the cable.

If the "accessory mode" is supported in the phone, it must recognize more than open or short, it must sense the ID impedance. If the pull-down resistor is between 122 and 126 kOhms, this should be recognized as accessory charger mode. In this case the phone will act as USB host but, instead of sourcing VBUS, it will accept the charge form VBUS.

For details of implementation and general ideas, see this Texas Instruments article, "[TSU6721 Accessory and Charger Detection Flow](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva665/slva665.pdf)". There are simple Y-split-looking cables on Amazon and e-Bay that have right ID and cable hookup that can provide the accessory charging mode.